# How to set timestamps in nested arrays

Tags: nestjs, typegoose

### Versions

- System: windows 10
- NodeJS: v12.16.2
- Typescript: v 4.1.3
- Compiler / Transpiler: tsc
- Typegoose(GIT): commithash
- mongoose: 5.10.18
- nestjs / nestjs-typegoose: 7.5.1 / 7.1.38

My question is how to set timestamps in nested arrays;

### Example code here

I tried the code:

```
@ModelOptions({ schemaOptions: { timestamps: true } })
class childModel {
  @prop()
  param:String
}

class parentModel {
  @prop({ type: childModel})
  child:childModel[]
}
```

When I saved this model: `parentModel.create( [{ param: 'xxx' }] )` , then the result is:

```js
{
child:[
  {
    param:'xxx',
    "createdAt": "2021-02-06T03:36:02.806Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-02-06T03:36:02.806Z"
  }
]
}
```

but what I want is:

```js
{
child:[
  [
    {
    param:'xxx',
    "createdAt": "2021-02-06T03:36:02.806Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-02-06T03:36:02.806Z"
    }
  ]
]
}
```

then I tried the code:

```
@ModelOptions({ schemaOptions: { timestamps: true } })
class childModel {
  @prop()
  param:String
}

class parentModel {
  @prop({type:[[childModel]]})
  child:childModel[][]
}
```

saved like this `parentModel.create( [ [ { param: 'xxx' } ] ] )` and result is:

```js
{
child:[
  [
    {
      param:'xxx'
    }
  ]
]
}
```

No timestamps here,why?

---

I have seen some other similar problems, but I still don't understand ; maybe my English is too poor to understand, if you know, please tell me straightly.

Also Created an Issue on the typegoose Repo [#485](https://github.com/typegoose/typegoose/issues/485)

Comment: Why are you trying to do an array of arrays? What's the use case over just an array of `childModel`?

Comment: as per your expected output, the parent model supposed to have `child:childModel[][]`

Comment: I just want to use two-dimensional arrays and  I really want to know how to do that.  Maybe I can manually add a timestamp field, but it's not elegant or cool enough